# SimpleFlip View first image coming back from json doesn't show immediately in winjs

Tags: winjs, flipview

I have a simple WINJS flipview. There are 5 images loaded from an external json file. All the images load immediately except the first one, and second question is there a simple command to automatically set these to rotate?

So we are using a single page model app. This is a little promo slider I wanted to put in on one page and rotate. I've tried everything including just the demo, but the first item always comes back undefined.

I even tried removing the first image, but the first item always comes back undefined. I've spent a few days on this now with not much luck.

```
    <div id="promoTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none" >
           <div class="overlaidItemTemplate">
            <img class="image" data-win-bind="src: picture" />
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2 class="ItemTitle" data-win-bind="innerText: title"></h2>
            </div>
        </div>             
    </div>
    <div id="promoFlipView" class="flipView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.FlipView" data-win-options="{ itemDataSource: ActivityPromoData.bindingList.dataSource, itemTemplate: select('#promoTemplate') }">
    </div>
```

This is connected to the demo example flipview Data

//// THIS CODE AND INFORMATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF
//// ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO
//// THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A
//// PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
////
//// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved

(function () {
    "use strict";

```
// This is an array that will be used to drive the FlipView in several
// scenarios. The array contains objects with the following attributes:
//
//      type - There are two types that are used:
//
//              item -
//                     The type for simple items.  It informs the custom
//                     renderer that their is a title and picture that needs
//                     to be rendered.
//
//              contentsArray -
//                     This is used for creating a table of contents.  It
//                     informs the renderer that an array of data is present
//                     for use in constructing the Table of Contents.
//
//      title - The title of a photo to be displayed.
//
//      picture - The location of the photo to be displayed.
var array = [
    { type: "item", title: "Cliff", picture: "images/Cliff.jpg" },
    { type: "item", title: "Grapes", picture: "images/Grapes.jpg" },
    { type: "item", title: "Rainier", picture: "images/Rainier.jpg" },
    { type: "item", title: "Sunset", picture: "images/Sunset.jpg" },
    { type: "item", title: "Valley", picture: "images/Valley.jpg" }
];
var bindingList = new WinJS.Binding.List(array);

WinJS.Namespace.define("ActivityPromoData", {
    bindingList: bindingList,
    array: array
});

var e = ActivityPromoData.bindingList.dataSource;
```

})();

The original question above here is the FIRST IMAGE BUG FIX: adding this to the onready. This works providing there is no custom animations.

```
  var proxyObject;
  proxyObject = new WinJS.Binding.as({
    itemTemplate: tutorialTemplate,
    customAnimations: false
  });
```

tutorialFlipView.winControl.itemTemplate = tutorialTemplate;

Comment: Shoutouts to simpleflips

Answer (score 0):

There is not builtin command to rotate. `setInternval()` can be used for this.

```
var timerId = setInternal(function() 
{
    if (flipview.winControl.count - 1 == flipview.winControl.currentPage)
        flipview.winControl.currentPage = 0;
    else
        flipview.winControl.next();
}, slideshowInternal);

// to stop slideshow
clearInterval(timerId);
```

This assumes no complex transition between pages (for example: KENBURNS). if that is required, it is more involved problem, and it is good to consider using some existing javascript sdk on web and integrate in a custom winjs control. flipview control did not work well when integrating custom page transition animations.

regards image not loading - html/js code snippet will help  answer it.

if `<img>` tag is used and bound it to the http image url, image is not guaranteed to be loaded when flipview shows the page. If number of images are handful, it might be better to download them using `winjs.xhr` to ensure that they are in cache and then, load the flipview.

Comment: Yeah the images are local and not external so don't think xhr is the right approach.

Comment: share html/js if possible. local images should load without issues

Comment: So apparently this is a longstanding BUG - it even has a name "The First Image" Problem. It stems from the fact that winprocess all doesn't seem to work correct when using a single page (navigation) model.  I'll post the work around that we had to finally do and discovered in the Professional Win 8 win js book.